# How to use react to draw the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I need to create map with react, now I have multiple objects with different altitudes. But I don't know how to draw multiple maps for each object on single page. Can anyone tell me how to do that? a brief example would be a big plus

Answer (score 0):

You should read through the [React docs on lists](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components). You need to map/iterate over your objects when rendering.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const mapData = [{a: 123,},{a:345}]; //Your map data
    return <div>
      {mapData.map((data)=>{
        ///Render your maps
        return <div>{data.a}</div>
      })}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRRzxy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great component [built for React](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react)

Sample usage

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

class SimpleMap extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {lat: 59.95, lng: 30.33},
    zoom: 11
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMapReact
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
      >
        <AnyReactComponent
          lat={59.955413}
          lng={30.337844}
          text={'Kreyser Avrora'}
        />
      </GoogleMapReact>
    );
  }
}
```